# Exporting Calendar to Excel throws an error

Tags: sharepoint-server, export-to-excel

I am trying to export a calendar with a list view in chrome,however I am getting the following error:

```
WEB
1
https://[site]/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?XMLDATA=1&List={3552683E-AA60-440B-BE31-015A31B047D2}&View={97BC28B7-DF5A-4627-B1D4-76C3B9D89DDA}&RowLimit=0&RootFolder=[site]%2fLists%2fCalGRP

Selection={3552683E-AA60-440B-BE31-015A31B047D2}-{97BC28B7-DF5A-4627-B1D4-76C3B9D89DDA}
EditWebPage=
Formatting=None
PreFormattedTextToColumns=True
ConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne=True
SingleBlockTextImport=False
DisableDateRecognition=False
DisableRedirections=False
SharePointApplication=https://abc/_vti_bin
SharePointListView={97BC28B7-DF5A-4627-B1D4-76C3B9D89DDA}
SharePointListName={3552683E-AA60-440B-BE31-015A31B047D2}
RootFolder=[site]/Lists/CalGRP
```

Any Idea

PS: I know that it runs in Edge and Firefox, but the intention is to figure out why it does not run in chrome and how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Export to Excel does not work from Google Chrome.

Make sure you use Internet Explorer Browser and check if the issue still exists.

Comment: Sorry, that much I have figured out. I want to find a solution to the above problem in chrome.

Comment: since export to excel functionality requires Active X control which Chrome doesn't support. As a workaround, you can add code into a script editor web part into list view page to export the data to excel. check the simialr post: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/39cb7e5a-719f-4ee7-8ff9-38911e1fd70e/export-to-excel-functionality-in-sharepoint-2013-lists-amp-libraries-not-working-in-chrome-browser?forum=sharepointdevelopment